# Ouucre Error:java.io.IOException: invalid header field

Tags: java, web-services, resteasy

I am getting error when i run my application using tomcat 6.0 server...

> I don't understand what exactly I'm missing?

Here, I have developed a resteasy Webservice example in which I have a `Student`class with getters and setters
Also I have a `List<Student>`also with a  getter setter and finally i have one `Service` class that contain business logic..all class is up to date..

> **But Still i m getting : :java.io.IOException: invalid header field ....**

```
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4296)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Please tell me what i have actual missing....?

Answer (score 1):

This error is causing by the mismatch order between “m” and “f” Jar options. Refer this link [Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jar-manifest-error-java-io-ioexception-invalid-header-field/)

Comment: In manifest file how to define the code...?My code is us Below Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: